# NuGet Package restore failed for project

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package

I'm a new xamarin developer.
I ran into an error while running my first project:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project Project.Droid: Unable to find version '2019' of package 'syncfusion.xamarin.linq.Android' not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open the .csproj in Notepad  and manually remove all entries related to the Package
3. Open packages.config in Notepad and remove the entry for the NuGet Package
4. Go to packages/ folder in Windows Explorer and delete the package folder

end

you can open a solution.